# CSS don't change the font in some HTML docs

Tags: html, css, fonts

In advance sorry for poor English.

Here is my situation. 
I have two HTML documents which have style,size,color,alignment stored in CSS file. 
I checked out,everything is linked properly,but font shows up properly in first document only,in second one it seems like there is no font set at all (shows default font). 
Strange thing is that,when I change size in CSS file, it changes it in both HTML documents.(but not font).

Where is possible mistake?

**EDIT:**

I used dev tools in chrome and it shows me that connection between CSS file and HTML is OK.

Here the code:

1.HTML

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Список завдань</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/css/theme.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&subset=cyrillic-ext,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  

<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/images/mark.png"/>
</head> 
<body background="https://pizzamaker.github.io/images/linedpaper.png">   
    <div id="nazwa">Tasks</div> 
<center>   
<div id="middle">
<table border="1">   
    <tr> 
    <td>1</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/1.html">Додайте всі натуральні числа до тисячі, які кратні 3 або 5.</a></td></tr>

    <tr>
        <td>2</td> 
        <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/2.html">Знайдіть суму всіх парних елементів ряду Фібоначчі, не більших чотирьох мільйонів.</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td>3</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/3.html">Знайдіть найбільший дільник складеного числа, який є простим числом.</a></td></tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td>4</td>
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/4.html">Знайдіть найбільший паліндром, отриманий сумою двох трьохзначних чисел.</a>
</td></tr>
    <tr> 
    <td>5</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/5.html">Яке найменше число ділиться без остачі на всі числа від 1 до 20?

    <tr> 
    <td>6</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/6.html">Яка різниця між сумою квадратів та квадратом суми?

    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td>7</td> 
    <td>
    <a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/7.html">Знайдіть 10001-ше просте число.</a>
    </td></tr>
    <tr> 
    <td>8</td> 
    <td> 
    <a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/8.html">Знайдіть найбільшу суму з послідовності п'яти цифр в 1000-значному числі.</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td>9</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/9.html">Здайдіть єдину трійку Піфагора {a, b, c}, для котрої a + b + c = 1000.</a></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td>10</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/10.html">Порахуйте суму всіх простих чисел меньше двох мільйонів.</a></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td>11</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/11.html">Найбільша множина чотирьох чисел в лінії таблиці 20х20?</a></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td>12</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/12.html">Яке перше трикутне число, у якого більше п'ятиста дільників?</a></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td>13</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/13.html">Знайдіть перші десять чесел суми наступних ста 50-значних чисел.</a></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td>14</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/14.html">Знайдіть найдовшу послідовність з початковим елементом меньше мільйона.
    </a></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr>  
    <td>15</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/15.html">Як багато маршрутів існує в таблиці 20х20, починаючи з лівого верхнього кута та закінчуючи правим нижнім?</a></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td>16</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/16.html">Яка сума цифр числа 2<img src="" style="display:none;" alt="^(" /><sup>1000</sup><img src="" style="display:none;" alt=")" />?</a></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td>17</td>
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/17.html">Скільки літер потрібно для написання усіх чисел від 1 до 1000 словами?</a></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td>18</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/18.html">Знайдіть максимальну суму шляху з вершини трикутника до його основи.</a></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td>19</td>  
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/19.html">Скільки  неділь випадають на перше число місяця в двадцатому столітті?</a></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td>20</td> 
    <td><a href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/tasks/20.html">Знайдіть суму цифр в числі 100!.</a></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
</div></center> 
</body>
</html>
```

2.HTML

```
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Завдання 1</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/css/theme.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&subset=cyrillic-ext,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>   
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="https://pizzamaker.github.io/images/mark.png"/>
</head> 
<body background="https://pizzamaker.github.io/images/linedpaper.png">                                                              
<div id="nazwa">1</div>  
<div id="middle">   
<p>Якщо написати усі натуральні числа меньше 10, які є кратні 3 або 5, то отримаємо 3, 5, 6 і 9. Сума цих чисел - 23.</p>
<p>Додайте всі натуральні числа до тисячі, які кратні 3 або 5.</p> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

3.CSS

```
#nazwa {
    font-family:'Fredericka the Great',cursive;
    font-size:4.4em; 
    text-align:center;
}

#middle {
    font-family:'Roboto Slab',serif;
    color:#000;
    margin-left:12em;
    margin-right:12em
}

strong {
    text-decoration:underline
}

#numbers {
    font-family:'Droid Serif',serif
}

h2 {
    font-family:'Roboto Slab',serif;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center
}

#header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    background-image:url(https://pizzamaker.github.io/images/linedpaper.png)
}

#button {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px
}

#euler {
    margin-top:14em;
    padding:1px;

}

a:link {
    color:#000
}

a:visited {
    color:#000
}

a:hover {
    color:#000
}

a:active {
    color:#000
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse
}
```

Comment: What browsers are you using? Can you show your code so we can better help?

Comment: Some example code would help a lot.  We can't check to make sure you aren't accidentally missing a stupid error without it.

Comment: I recommend looking at your site through the developer tools in the browsers of your choice. It will enable you to trace where the styles on a particular element are coming from

Comment: I am using Chromium. As you see, the site is on github pages and you see link in href's.

Comment: Its working fine for me, with font and all

Answer (score 0):

Your fonts are not being applied to the 1st HTMl file because it does not feature `#middle`, meaning the CSS is working fine.

To fix this, you simply need to add the appropriate `id` to the 1st HTML file like so:

```
<body background="https://pizzamaker.github.io/images/linedpaper.png">   
    <div id="nazwa">Tasks</div>  
    <div id="middle">
        TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
    </div>
</body>
```

On a related note, your 1st HTML file doesn't have tags around your main text. You will need to wrap your text with `<p>`s or similar, as you have in the 2nd HTML file. Consistency will save you 90% of errors, and speeds up solving them too!

Lastly, you don't need inline styles on your `<body >` tag to apply the background, you can do all that in your CSS like so:

```
body {
    background-image: url(https://pizzamaker.github.io/images/linedpaper.png);    
}
```